# how to get tree instance in controller - Ext 4

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I have a small problem to get the instance of my tree in controller. Well, without the MVC pattern it looks like this and it works fine.

```
var tree = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    tbar : [{
        text : 'Delete',
            handler : function() {
                var record = tree.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];
                record.remove(true);
                tree.getView().refresh();
            } 
    }]
});
```

Then I have created the MVC pattern and I would like to get the tree reference, so that I would be able to call the method `getSelectionModel()` etc. (like what I did on the above code).

```
Ext.define("MyApp.controller.GridPanelTreeController", {
    views: ["GridPanelTree"],
    refs   : [{
        ref: "controllerDataSelector",
        selector: "tree"
    }],

    init: function(){
        this.control({
            "toolbar button[action=delete] " : {
                click : this.delete
            }
        });
    },

    delete : function() {
        /* this returns an error, that tree is undefined*/
        var tree = this.getControllerDataSelector();
        var record = tree.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];

        /* this returns an error, that TypeError: tree.getSelectionModel is not a function */
        var tree = this.getGridPanelTreeView();
        var record = tree.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];
     }
```

I have no idea why it does not work properly. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Just FYI, `delete` is a javascript keyword, and you shouldn't use it as the name of a function.

Comment: No, I have just change the function name and it still does not work as expected.

Comment: add `action` property to button

Comment: Well, I have the action property. The function in the controller is called, when the click on the button appears. The problem is, that I can not get the view reference and delete a node from the view in my controller. I have tried two different methods from above, but as I have written in the comment, it does not work properly. Hm, maybe the problem is somewhere else?

Comment: log tree on console & check what do you see, `refs` selector works based on `xtype` or `itemId`,if `tree` is `itemId` then it should be like `#tree`, & xtype for `tree` is `treepanel`

Comment: Well, I have logged tree on console. If I use the method getControllerDataSelector(), which is based on ref, the console logs "undefined" . If I use getGridPanelTreeView(), which is based on views, than I get object. In my component I have just an alias, like alias: widget.controllerDataSelector. And this one I use in my controller in refs.

Comment: try setting `controllerDataSelector` in `selector` of `refs` instead of `tree`

Comment: Thank you very much, now it works. Hm, I'm just wondering why should I change in my refs the selector tree to controllerDataSelector . I thought in refs the selector and the ref dont have to be the same.

Comment: `ref` can be any value, based on that it will generate the getter method, but selector must be valid selector e.g itemId/xtype

Answer (score 0):

You need see arguments of function.

```
delete : function(btn) {

    var tree = btn.scope;
    var record = tree.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];


 }
```